# VS2010 Code Templates - Centrally Store and Distribute?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to centrally store and distribute code templates such that they can be pushed out to other members of a team?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd keep the code in some sort of version control for obvious reasons, but I'm assuming your wanting to know how to share the templates automatically.  I've never done what your asking but the templates should be stored in the \My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Templates\ProjectTemplates directory in visual studio 2008 anyway.  You may be able to map this directory or one of the subdirectories to a network share where you can store your team templates.

Please let us know what the solution eventually is, because this sounds like a very useful idea.